# Dropdown inside dropdown Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have this html that is supposed to be a dropdown inside another dropdown.
The hierarchy is:

```
Dropdown
  |_ First Dropdown
  |     |_ aaa
  |     |_ bbb
  |     |_ ccc
  |_ Second Dropdown
        |_ ddd
```

They look fine, but when I press on `First Dropdown`, the dropdown with values `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc` won't show up. Same with `Second Dropdown`.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <div class="btn-group dropright">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          First Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>aaa</li>
          <hr>
          <li>bbb</li>
          <hr>
          <li>ccc</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <hr>
    <li>
      <div class="btn-group dropright">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Second Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>ddd</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Which seems to be the problem? Thank you for your time!

Comment: How is this related with angular? I just see bootstrap classes in your html

Comment: I wanted to make sure in case somebody will give me a solution, it won't use `javascript`.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the purpose of this: so you have two dropdown inside one? can't you have two and populate the second from the first?

Comment: Please use HTML <optgroup> Tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

Comment: Inside `First Dropdown` and `Second Dropdown` I will have many values, I don't want them all to be visible..

Answer (score 1):

So you can kinda achieve this with angular material [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

you have `<mat-select>` there wich is a kinda dropdown menu and `<mat-option>` wich is an entry in a mat-select

however you can use a mat select inside of a mat option wich itself is a dropdown inside a dropdown.

```
<mat-select>entry
 <mat-option>hu
  <mat-select>
   <mat-option>hallo</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-option>
 <mat-option>hi
  <mat-select>hello
   <mat-option>hallo</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-option>
 <mat-option>hui
  <mat-select>
   <mat-option>hallo</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```